# MSVC 2015 GetComputerName unresolved external symbol issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

There are three dynamic link libraries: A, B, C.

The Library A exports two functions: `IsRemoteSession()` and `GetComputerName()` in `system` namespace.

The Library B has a static linkage with a library A and use both functions. There are no link errors.

The Library C has a static linkage with a library A and use both functions. There is a link error:

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol “GetComputerName” in debug and release configurations.

The project properties of B and C are identical.

There are no link errors in MSVC 2008.

The only one workaround I’ve found is to rename GetComputerName to something else.

Anyone else encountered this error?

P.S.
`#undef GetComputerName` does not help.

Comment: [GetComputerName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724295.aspx) is also the name of a Windows API call. Like all other Windows API calls that pass string parameters, it is a preprocessor symbol that expands to either `GetComputerNameA` or `GetComputerNameW`. You are probably exporting or importing a symbol different from the one you think you are.

Comment: Yes, I know but: 
The Library B has a static linkage with a library A and use both functions. **There are no link errors**. and `#undef GetComputerName` does not help.

Comment: Still, though, with the information provided, this question isn't answerable. A [mcve] is needed, that ideally includes the *exact* error message, as well as DUMPBIN output from the LIB file.

Comment: My guess is that the the order of include of `windows.h` plays a role and renames all your `GetComputerName` in both B and A, but not in C. The linker cannot find it because its called .something like `GetComputerNameA` or `GetComputerNameW` in A. For the test you can look at the exports or try `#define GetComputerNameA` or `W` in C.

Comment: @A
@IInspectable
Thanks guys, that is it. GetComputerName turned into GetComputerNameA. `#undef GetComputerName` in library A did a trick.

Comment: That is not a solution. If you `#undef GetComputerName` in library A only, you are still trying to import the wrong symbols in libraries B and C. You have to make sure to use the same symbol in all 3 places. Also consider using [push_macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/push-macro)/[pop_macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pop-macro) to leave the global namespace as you found it.

Comment: @IInspectable
That is exactly what i did.

Comment: @IInspectable the problem is that the "simple" Windows define renamed the symbol in both A and B, but not in C because wasn't included with A's includes or before. I agree renaming to xxA is not a solution. Maybe including windows.h before include A's header is less bad

Answer (score 0):

This is because of '#define' in `windows.h`.

It renamed all my `GetComputerName` to `GetComputerNameA` in both A and B libraries but not C.